# PLS-DA on sklearn: correlated features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to retrieve the groups of features that, jointly, show a high loading in each LV. I'm aware that I can retrieve this by digging into `x_loadings_`, but given that covariance within and between groups is maximized, I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve the combinations of features rather than individual features?

**TL;DR: How to get strongly correlated features? Can we define these by their fitting coefficients?**

This is how I'm performing the PLS-DA

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
plsr=PLSRegression(n_components=2, scale=True)
plsr_fit=plsr.fit(input_data, y)

#x scores
plsr_fit.x_scores_

#x loadings
plrs_fit.x_loadings_

#x weights
plrs_fit.x_weights_
```

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284737/partial-least-squares-regression-plsr-regression-coefficients-vs-correlation)

Answer (score 0):

PCA/PLS results are hard to Interpret, because you do not know the feature_mixture present in pc_scores, that are the results of dimensionality reduction -- and of course, reducing dimensionality you're loosing some info (exactly things what you're asking about). The only you can do (not you're interested in) is to [reconstruct your initial data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249143/reconstruction-of-original-dataset-through-loadings-in-pca) ([from eigenvectors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344496/pca-reconstruction-from-a-clean-set-of-eigenvectors)) or see here for [computer_version](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com)... In any case, I consider, the answer to your question is NO you can't know what set of features mostly input to your highest loadings, because this information is already reduced. Though - can see [here](https://nirpyresearch.com/pca-correlation-circle/) - if it's enough for you

Frankly speaking in sklearn PCA fitted result-object you can see its properties for **weights**, but personally I see no reason to do dim_reduction and next explore (try to decompose) components back to features (because you have only weight for the certain point, not the whole sample)

p.s. though [there is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues/35653#35653) terminologic difference between *eigenvectors* and *loadings*